# How to display # sign in URL (MVC route config)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url, routes, asp.net-mvc-5

I have following route defined in route.config file of my MVC project:

```
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "CountriesByContinent",
        url: "countries/{continent_name}#{continent_id}",
        defaults: new { controller = MVC.Geography.Name, action = MVC.Geography.ActionNames.CountriesIndex }
        );
```

When I browse through the page, the generated URL converts # into its ASCII value which is %23
For example - ... /countries/asia%231

I know # symbol is supported in URLs, for example (gmail.com/mail/#inbox, etc)

Any idea of how to make URLs displaying # symbol?

Any help on this much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fragment identifier is not sent to the server, you can only use it from JavaScript in the browser.

Comment: @Nirman "fragment identifier" == `#foo` portion of URL, just in case you're unfamiliar with the term.